# How can I properly set the debug information path for Qt sources in Qt Creator (MinGW)?

Tags: qt, debugging, gdb, qt-creator, mingw32

I'm using Qt Creator 10.0.2 in Windows.
My building kit is Qt 5.15.2 and it's installed using official Qt online installer, the version is opensource.
The components I've installed shown below:

[image]

The kit is installed by default to C:\Qt\5.15.2 which contains "Src" (source code) and "mingw81_64" folders. In mingw81_64 I have Qt libraries in the "bin" folder, and *.dll.debug debug information files in the "lib" folder respectively.

When I'm starting to debug, for example, in main.cpp I have QApplication constructor, which I stepping into. I can do it only in assembly code mode. But I can't switch to the C++ source code. The error I see is shown bellow in a tooltip:

[image]

It says:

> "Binary debug information is not accessible for this frame. This either means the core was not compiled with debug information, or the debug information is not accessible."

I have tried this command for GDB:

`set debug-file-directory C:\Qt\5.15.2\mingw81_64\lib`

But that doesn't seem to help.

But when I copy content of "lib" folder into "bin" folder everything works fine. So it seems like GDB can't find debug information path properly. So the question is how to set that path. Should I do it myself? Shouldn't that functionality work out of box after installation?

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76639550/edit). Thanks in advance.